# How to freeze all Cordova dependencies?

Tags: node.js, docker, cordova, npm, offline

I'm building a Cordova app where tight control over the build environment is part of the spec/business requirements.

I'd like to (a) figure out the version and binary file and url for EVERY dependency, and (b) make sure they NEVER update automatically.

I'd like to use this to set up a Docker image for a build, and/or a local mirror of all dependencies.  If the Docker image can be regenerated from the mirror that is best; if the Docker image works fine without a network connection (including cordova platform rm/add...) that is a close second.

Unfortunately, the number of dependencies (including dependencies of dependencies etc) is massive, and worse, there are many completely different kinds of packages with different package management systems.

Some of the things I know about:

- npm packages -> list in package.json, installed in node_modules/, downloaded from npmjs.com
- cordova platforms -> list in config.xml, installed in platforms/  (from npm?)
- cordova plugins -> list in config.xml, installed in plugins/  (from npm?)
- gradle? from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/
- bintray packages?
- maven packages?
- for Android - platform-tools, build-tools etc, downloaded using tools/bin/sdkmanager from ?
- for iOS - Xcode and a bunch of other things?

How can I get a handle on all of these?  Is this an already solved problem (and how)?

It seems like this would be something that everyone who cares about versioning but wants to use Javascript/Node-type tools would need to solve; however there seems to be an almost total lack of documentation on it.

Comment: If your using docker the images are locked anyway.  Nothing should be automatically updating.  If your going to be doing docker builds again, use specific version tags and not latest.

Comment: @Keith - True, the docker image is locked; but there are so many operations that do trigger automatic updates and fail if there is no network.  I simply want to run builds on the assumption there is no network whatsoever; for any dependency (eg cordova add plugin...) I want to resolve it from a file, and if the file is not there then fail.

Comment: So your wanting to do docker builds again, but you might not have network access.  In this case you could setup a personal registry server.  There are lots of registry servers you can use, some specific.  Eg docker itself has an image for it's registry.  But there are registry servers that do multiple ones for npm etc.  Private registry's also act as a cache so benefits there too.